# Auto generate /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: dns, resolv.conf, resolvconf

I have manually edited `/etc/resolvconf/base` to add `openDNS` name servers, and then run `sudo resolvconf -u` to update the `/etc/resolv.conf`file.

However changes are discarded on each reboot.

How do I preserve those changes?

```
$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.3 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

**edit**:

```
/home/pkaramol
$ cat /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
/home/pkaramol
$ sudo resolvconf -u
/home/pkaramol
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN

nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

Comment: Do you use the GUI and have Network Manager running ? That will override/overwrite what you are doing in `resolv.conf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are placing the changes you want into the wrong directory.  NetManager allows custom configuration of the file by editing the **base**, **head** and **tail** by placing your preferences in this directory:

```
/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base
/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail
```

You can correct this by moving your `/etc/resolvconf/base` to `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base`.

The content you're seeing after reboot is the content of the `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` file.  It takes precedence over all and as you can see, is preserved.

The priority choices should be placed there.

Comment: Hi thx but pls check my **edit**

Comment: I have never used the `base` or the `tail`.  I always use the `head` so that my entry would take precedence.  Will you test the `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` option and post the results?  I had mentioned `base` because of the content of your question, which may loose to something else taking place.  The text in your email (`DO NOT EDIT`) is part of the `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` file which appears to be preserved.  I'll edit my answer based on the new content in your question.

Comment: yep...`head` seems to work even after the reboot..thx

Comment: Thanks!  Please consider accepting the answer by clicking the Grey checkmark.  It'll help others to easily find solutions that work.

Comment: just accepted  your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can add the nameservers in the `resolv.conf` and make it immutable, which means - it can not be modified.

```
echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' > /etc/resolv.conf
sudo chmod 444 /etc/resolv.conf
sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

That should do a trick. To modify the file again do: `sudo chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Its worked for me, thank you so much...